# Call is not going to fallback method of Resilience4 Circuit breaker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am using Resilience4j Circuit breaker version: '1.4.0 with Spring boot version 2.0.6 and my problem is - fallback method is not working. the call is not going to the fallback method.
Below is my code :

```
@Override
@CircuitBreaker(name="mainService",fallbackMethod = "callFallback")
public JSONObject callService(JSONObject rawRequest) throws TimeoutException {
      ...
       throw new TimeoutException("Time occured while calling 
       service");
      ...
}
```

-- and fallback method :

```
private JSONObject callFallback(JSONObject rawRequest,Throwable t){

    System.out.println("Inside fallback method callNsFallback, 
        cause"+t.toString());

        logger.info("Inside fallback method callFallback, 
        cause - {}",t.toString());

    return rawRequest;
}
```

--Configurations in application.yml

```
resilience4j:
circuitbreaker:
    configs:
    default:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 5
        ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState: 3
        slidingWindowSize: 10
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
        recordExceptions:
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    instances:
    mainService:
        baseConfig: default
```

Comment: Does it throw CallNotPermittedException without the fallback method?

Comment: Are you only capturing TimeoutException?

Comment: Thanks @SaifUrRahman for replying. Its didn't throw CallNotPermittedException and I was using only TimeoutException. The problem is resolved by adding 'spring- aop' dependancy with resilience4J

Comment: Ok. Could you please share your pom.xml as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The possible reasons could be you are missing some required dependencies. Here I am sharing the dependencies and the yaml configuration which were working for me.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      menu-service:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
        permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 1
        slidingWindowSize: 10
        waitDurationInOpenState: 2s
        slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED
        
        
management:
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been missing below dependency. It worked after adding and fallback method was called!

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```